# Where is log file of openproject?

Tags: debian, openproject

I have Openproject in my  debian 9 server. I couldn't find log file for openproject.

`/var/log/openproject`  is empty

I tried  openproject logs --tails

error

```
cat: '/var/log/openproject/*.log' : no such file or directory
```

Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
cat: '/var/log/openproject/*.log' : no such file or directory
```

This means that your OpenProject server probably isn't running. Please try to start the server first.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the syslog file.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Or use openproject command

```
openproject logs [--tail|-n NUMBER|-f]
```

Or use journal command

```
journalctl -u openproject-* -f
```